# Passing single string from forum in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having a problem trying to do this with one string but basically I want a form that has just a text box and a submit button that when submitted passes the value of the text box back to the controller as a string - so I can do arithmetic in the controller. Unfortunately I only understand ruby passing objects through forums.

The view (where the forum is):

```
<h1>Questions#go</h1>

<p>Just a quick question</p>

<%= form_for(@answer) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :answer %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :answer %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def go
  end

  # POST /go
  def submit
    @answer = :answer
    if @answer = 'Ted'
      @message = 'Correct'
    else
      @message = 'Incorrect'
    end
  end

end
```

Finally the routes:

```
Quizzer::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :quizzes

  get "questions/go"
  post "questions/go"

  match '/go', :to => 'questions#go'

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  get "pages/home"

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

I have been trying to teach myself basic rails for days and am seriously struggling. Basically what I am trying to achieve I wrote in Ruby as (yes I am learning RoR just to be able to implement this online):

```
class Quiz

  def initialize(name)
    puts "Welcome #{name}, I hope you brought your A-game."
    @count = 0
    @questions = ["What is 1 + 2 equal to?", "What is my name?", "What is the first letter of the alphabet?"]
    @answers = ["3", "NICK", "A"]
    @numberOfQuestions = @questions.length
    self.startGame
  end

  def startGame
    @gameOver = 0
    while (@gameOver == 0)
      self.playQuiz
      self.checkOverallWin
    end
  end

  def checkAnswer (givenAnswer)
    if (givenAnswer == @answers[@count])
      @count += 1
      puts "Well done you answered that correctly."
    else
      puts "Sorry wrong answer. Here it comes again!"
    end
    puts ""
  end

  def checkOverallWin
    if @count == @numberOfQuestions
      @gameOver = 1
      puts "Well done you have finished the quiz!"
    else
      @gameOver = 0
    end
  end

  def playQuiz
    puts "Question number #{@count + 1}:"
    puts @questions[@count]
    answer = gets()
    answer.upcase!
    answer.strip!
    self.checkAnswer(answer)
  end

end

puts "Hello, welcome to this simple game!"
puts "What is your name?"
name = gets()
name.strip!
game = Quiz.new(name)
```

Unfortunately every guide I have completed deals with objects and OO - which I dont need - I just want a way to pass text into the controller, check if it matches the required text and if so proceed with the 'next question' and show the input screen all over again.

Comment: Could you show your attempt at doing that?

Comment: Edited as above and my motivation behind why I am trying to do this in the first place for possibly a better solution.

Comment: Although if you're not taking the time to actually *learn* RoR, which is pretty trivial, IMO why bother? It's much easier to work with the framework than to work around it.

Comment: I am taking the time to learn RoR, atleast trying, just struggling to think of a way to implement my quiz application with the knowledge I have. I must have built atleast 5 microblogging and shop sites by now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `def submit` to read the `answer` (the string you want to process), you need to get it from `params` array:

```
@answer = params[:answer]
```

BTW, in Ruby everything is an object so there's no way you can escape them :)

If you think you're not getting what you have submitted, you can check request or request params by `puts request.inspect` or `puts params.inspect`.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that but it seemed to throw a problem. Can I just create an object in the definition of the forum or does that object need to be defined in a model?

Comment: No need for model. Don't think about objects if you're afraid of them. Think of what they are. You're working with strings, so they're strings for you. @answer is a string. You need to read that string from request parameters array which is called params.

Comment: That makes sense - always have been taught string is an object. Just difficult coming from a java world.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example, for the view:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'home', :action => 'arithmetic', :method => 'post') %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:my_thing) %>
<% end %>
```

Then the controller:

```
    class HomeController < ActionController::Base
    def arithmetic
        my_value = params[:my_thing]
    end
end
```

Untested, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Will test it, would I need to update my routes file to accomodate the post though?